# Can't route to CakePHP Controllers with Apache

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, routes

I have my own `digitalocean` droplet setup and followed this tutorial to a T to get `Cakephp` working

[Setup CakePHP with  LAMP Stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-cakephp-application-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Everything works exactly as written in that tutorial besides for 'Step 6' - Creating the Article user interface. (Books in my case)

After using the bake all command and navigating to `/books' I get a 404 not found

[image: Showing CakePHP works by navigating to top level URL]

[image: Showing CakePHP doesn't work after navigating past the top level URL to /books]

As you can see CakePHP is setup and working at the top level URL, however when trying to move past that to a Controller that definitely exists it can't find it.

Comment: Did you add htaccess file?

Comment: @Parth Patel Yes Parth, all 3 .htaccess files are in place and look correctly configured

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I found the issue.  Apparently mod_rewrite is turned off by default on Ubuntu

```
`sudo a2enmod rewrite
 systemctl reload apache`
```

is the solution here

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your rewrite mod is On**

If you are using Linux goto /etc/apache2/sites-enabled -> open 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
....

// add these lines
<Directory /var/www/html>
#Options FollowSymLinks
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>

....
<</VirtualHost>
```

Save it.

restart your server:  `sudo service apache2 restart`

**give your project permissions by giving this command:**

```
sudo chown -R user_name:www-data project_name/
sudo chmod -R 755 project_name/

cd project_name 

chown -R www-data tmp
chown -R www-data logs

chmod -R 777 tmp
chmod -R 777 logs
```